# Por que a ausência do sufixo L faz a variável long ser interpretada como int?

Tags: java, variáveis, tipagem, declaração-de-variável

Quando uso um número curto para `long`, como `long long1 = 9797;`, o número é aceito mesmo sem usar o sufixo `L`. No entanto, ao colocar um número maior - como seus valores mínimos e máximos, por exemplo - o valor só é aceito como `long` se utilizar o sufixo `L`, pois, do contrário, fala que está *out of range*.

Utilizei primeiro um valor menor que foi aceito sem problemas e sem necessidade de sufixo e depois valores maiores, que só foram aceitos com `L`:

```
public class Dúvida_sobre_long {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long long1 = 9797;
        long long2 = 922337203685477807;  // Erro de compilação nesta linha.
        long long3 = 922337203685477807L;

        System.out.println(long1);
        System.out.println(long2);
        System.out.println(long3);
    }

}
```

O erro de compilação é esse:

> The literal 922337203685477807 of type int is out of range.

Eu entendi que sem o sufixo `L`, o valor é interpretado como `int`, mas gostaria de saber o por quê isso acontece com valores maiores, já que eu especifiquei que a variável é `long`?

Comment: Só para complementar: valores `float` tem o mesmo comportamento. Se você fizer `float x = 10.0;` o `10.0` será um literal `double` e não um `float`. É necessário fazer `float x = 10.0F;` ou `float x = 10.0f;` para que o valor seja "verdadeiramente" `float`.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 13):

O porquê é que os criadores da linguagem decidiram assim. Não tem explicação melhor :) Está na [especificação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).

De fato o que está declarando ali é um literal `int` que é feito um *cast* pelo compilador implicitamente. Então está reservando um espaço de 8 bytes, o tamanho de um tipo `long` e guardando um valor inteiro que só precisaria 4 bytes, mas o resto é preenchido com zeros, então dá na mesma. Não há custo de execução algum, é só algo que o compilador tem que lidar quando está construindo o código.

Eles poderiam ter exigido colocar o sufixo `L` mesmo em casos de valores "baixos"? Sim, poderiam, mas não o fizeram, acharam que não era necessário. Pra mim é inconsistente, mas é assim e você deve seguir essas regras. Se quiser ser mais consistente coloque o `L` onde pode mesmo quando não precisa.

Eles poderiam ter deixado de exigir o sufixo em valores grandes pelo menos ali na declaração ou em casos que não tem ambiguidade e assim inferiria que é um longo mesmo? Poderiam. Provavelmente acharam que ficava ruim assim. Talvez acharam que adicionaria um trecho de código no compilador, e portanto um tempo de execução para tratar isso que acharam que não valia a pena.

Eu acho um custo irrisório perto do que eles que eles já fazem e pela inconsistência de comportamentos do compilador, hora ele precisa entender o que está à frente, hora não quer fazer isto. Mas o Java iniciou querendo um custo baixo, sem inferir nada. Hoje já infere algumas coisas.

Eu discordo da conclusão do Victor Stafusa, ainda que a resposta esteja correta e muito boa. Se quisessem simplificar o compilador exigiriam o sufixo em toda declaração em um `long`. Hoje o compilador faz exceções. Mas exceções não são o fim do mundo. Inferência próxima (do ponto de vista de análise de código) não gera grandes dificuldades para o compilador. Complicado é inferir por algo que está está distante. E algo parecido com inferência, pelo menos neste caso é feito de qualquer forma. Afinal ele tem que decidir que não tem ambiguidade e aceitar sem o sufixo. O compilador seria mais simples se tudo fosse obrigatório, mesmo um `0L`. Tudo o que está na resposta dele mostra que não simplificaram tanto assim. Ou simplifica de verdade, ou aceita resolver tudo, ficou um pé em cada canoa.

Parte do que ocorre é também porque Java foi baseada em linguagens que lidavam dessa forma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só pra complementar: o sufixo em letra minúscula também é valido (`l`), só não é legal de usar porque parece o número `1`.

Comment: O que alias é outra bobagem, já que é ruim, nem deveria permitir, e ainda mataram o sufixo que poderia ser útil no futuro (nem tanto por ele, mas todos os outros).

Comment: Link relevante: [especificação da linguagem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

Comment: Sim, concordo. Era só pra complementar mesmo, por que para valores `float`, é "aceitável" usar o sufixo tanto em letra minúscula quanto maiúscula.

Answer (score 9):

## A estrutura do compilador

Internamente, o compilador é dividido em várias partes: Análise léxica; análise sintática, análise semântica, geração de código e otimização de código.

A primeira dessas partes, a análise léxica, é responsável por picotar o código-fonte em *tokens*. Por exemplo, ao escrever `public static void main(String[] args) {`, o analisador léxico vai ver 11 diferentes *tokens*: `public`, `static`, `void`, `main`, `(`, `String`, `[`, `]`, `args`, `)`e `{`. Além disso, a análise léxica já faz uma classificação básica do *token*: `public`, `static` e `void` são palavras-chave da linguagem; `main` e `String` são identificadores, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` e `{` são símbolos especiais. Identação e comentários são descartados pela análise léxica e não constituem *tokens*.

Na análise sintática, os *tokens* serão agrupados para que o compilador tente entender a estrutura do programa. Nesta etapa, ele vai ver que modificadores de acesso (`public` e `static`) seguidos de um tipo `void`, seguido de um nome `main`, seguido de uma lista de parâmetros entre parênteses corresponde a declaração de um método.

A análise sintática transforma o código em uma estrutura em forma de árvore, onde abaixo do nó que representa a classe, temos nós que representam campos, construtores e métodos. Dentro dos nós que representam métodos, temos nós que representam o tipo de retorno, os modificadores, os parâmetros, as exceções e o corpo. Dentro de cada nó que corresponde ao corpo de um método, temos vários outros nós que correspondem a cada instrução do método.

A análise semântica é a etapa responsável por verificar se o programa obtido da análise sintática faz sentido, verificando se todas as variáveis usadas foram declaradas e inicializadas, se todos os métodos chamados existem e têm os parâmetros dos tipos corretos, se não há variáveis com nomes repetidos no mesmo escopo, etc.

## Os literais `int` e `long`

A análise léxica ao encontrar um `9797` irá emitir um *token* do tipo literal `int` e ao encontrar um `9797L` irá emitir um *token* do tipo literal `long`. A resposta para a sua dúvida é que **a diferenciação é feita na análise léxica**. Veja [**aqui**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) a especificação léxica dessa parte.

Para que o analisador léxico saiba distinguir o literal `int` do literal `long`, resolveram que se tem o sufixo `L` ou `l`, então é um literal `long`, se não, é um literal `int`. Essa é uma regra bem simples e bem fácil de se entender.

## Não daria para ser diferente?

É verdade que podiam fazer de outro jeito, mas o projeto do compilador fica mais fácil se o analisador léxico já puder separar os literais `int`s dos literais `long`s, ao custo de colocar esse detalhe na linguagem com o sufixo `l` ou `L`. O mesmo ocorre com o literal `float` que necessita do sufixo `f` ou `F` para diferenciar do literal `double`.

A necessidade de haver esses literais expressos justifica-se em especial com a presença do autoboxing:

```
Object a = 555;
Object b = 555L;
System.out.println(a.getClass().getName()); // java.lang.Integer
System.out.println(b.getClass().getName()); // java.lang.Long
```

Sem a presença do sufixo, construir-se o 555 como `long` iria exigir um cast.

Se não houvesse esse sufixo `L`, você teria que usar isso para criar um `long` sem o sufixo:

```
long y = (long) 922337203685477807;
```

Mas isso não funciona porque o número 922337203685477807 já está fora da faixa válida para o `int`, então não dá para construí-lo antes de fazer o cast. Ele necessariamente deve ser construído como `long`. Aí temos o sufixo `L` para isso.

Poderiam ter feito que esses números já são `long` por padrão, mas aí na hora de usar isso:

```
int x = 555;
```

Você teria um problema porque o literal é `long` e a variável é `int`. Para resolver isso ou você teria que colocar um sufixo nos `int`s, o que seria bem pior (ter que usar `555i` ao invés de `555`), ou teria que usar casts explícitos para `int` sempre, que seria horrível, uma vez que `int`s estão em todos os lugares.

Uma outra possibilidade seria o compilador fazer uma análise contextual para saber se o número cabe no `int` ou não. Mas isso não é viável. Por exemplo:

```
int f = 150096 * g - h / 5;
```

Como saber se isso cabe ou não no `int` sem usar casts e nem sufixos específicos? Até é possível fazer, mas isso complica bastante a análise sintática e semântica do compilador para resolver um detalhezinho simples da linguagem. Ou seja, complicaria bastante a estrutura do compilador.

Outra possibilidade seria o analisador léxico verificar se o número está na faixa do `int`, emitindo um *token* de literal `int` se estiver ou um literal `long` se não estiver. Mas isso teria efeitos colaterais um tanto confusos:

```
Object a = 2147483647;        // java.lang.Integer
Object b = (long) 2147483647; // java.lang.Long - Tem que ter o cast
Object c = 2147483648;        // java.lang.Long - Surpresa! Agora não precisa mais do cast.
```

No caso do `byte` e do `short`, não há literais para eles, o que é muito chato e portanto casts sempre são necessários a partir de `int`, `long` ou `char`. Por exemplo:

```
byte b = (byte) 123;
short s = (short) 1234L;
```

Entretanto, como o `int` e o `long` são maiores que o `byte` e o `short`, o cast pode ser usado, diferentemente do caso do `long` para o `int`.

No caso do `float` e do `double`, ocorre o inverso porque o tipo menor é que exige o sufixo, o que livra o tipo maior de ter que fazê-lo. Adotar o mesmo em relação ao `int` e ao `long` não seria prático porque significaria que o `int` é que teria que ter o sufixo (`555i`).